# How to relax an Integer Linear Programming model and describe it as a minimal cost flow problem?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, programming, network-flow

I have the following Integer Linear Programming model:

$\text{min} Z = 6x_{1,3} + 5x_{1,4} + 2x_{1,2} + 3x_{2,3} + 5x_{2,4} + 2x_{3,5} + 4x_{4,5} + 100(y_{1,3} + y_{1,4} + y_{1,2} + y_{2,3} + y_{2,4} + y_{3,5} + y_{4,5})$

The constraints are :

$y_{i,j} = \begin{cases}1 \text{ if  } x_{i,j} > 0 \\ 0 \text{ if } x_{i,j} = 0 \end{cases}$

$x_{1,3} + x_{1,4} + x_{1,2} \leq 20$

$x_{1,3} \leq 10$

$x_{1,4} \leq 20$

$x_{1,2} \leq 20$

$x_{2,3} + x_{2,4} \leq 30$

$x_{2,3} \leq 25$

$x_{2,4} \leq 30$

$x_{3,5} \leq 30$

$x_{4,5} \leq 30$

Now I'm tasked with relaxing the above model and to describe it as a minimal cost flow problem.

What I'm trying to do is to first come up with a minimal cost flow problem without taking into account the binary variables of the previous model.

This is what I get:

$\text{min} Z = 6x_{1,3} + 5x_{1,4} + 2x_{1,2} + 3x_{2,3} + 5x_{2,4} + 2x_{3,5} + 4x_{4,5} $

With the following constraints :

$ x_{1,3} + x_{1,4} + x_{1,2} = 20 $

$ x_{2,3} + x_{2,4} - x_{1,3} = 10 $

$ x_{3,5} - (x_{1,3} + x_{2,3}) = 0$

$ x_{3,5} - (x_{1,4} + x_{2,4}) = 0$

$ -(x_{3,5} + x_{4,5}) = -30$

How can I take into account the binary variables of the first model in this minimal cost flow problem?

Comment: As stated, the optimal solution to the original problem is trivial: $x=0=y$. An equivalent min cost flow problem would be to run 0 units of flow over the underlying network. Is the original problem perhaps misstated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To link the $x$ and $y$ variables, let $M_{i,j}$ be a constant upper bound on $x_{i,j}$ and introduce linear big-M constraints
$$x_{i,j} \le M_{i,j} y_{i,j}$$
that enforce $x_{i,j} > 0 \implies y_{i,j} = 1$.
For example $M_{1,3} = 10$.

Comment: Does relaxation implies that you can have non integer values for y? Also I fail to see how adding big-M constraints to the minimal cost flow problem would allow me to take into account the cost 100 that happens when you have $x_{i,j} > 0$ like in the first model. This 100 cost is incurred each time a $y_{i,j} = 1$ in the first model.

Comment: If $x_{i,j}>0$ and integrality of $y_{i,j}$ is imposed, the big-M constraints enforce $y_{i,j}=1$, which would incur $100$ in the objective.  Relaxing $y_{i,j}$ to be continuous will not correctly model the fixed charge of $100$.

Comment: Where in the second model does the cost of 100 is incurred with BigM constraints? This what I fail to see.

Comment: Use your original objective function.

Comment: Ok but my task is to go from a linear programming model to a minimal cost flow problem after having relaxed the initial linear programming model. I fail to see how adding big M constraints achieves this.

Comment: The problem is not convex, so you will not be able to formulate as a pure network flow problem. Maybe the intent of the exercise is to replace $c_{i,j}$ with $c_{i,j}+100/M_{i,j}$ in the objective. Doing that would underestimate the true objective, providing a relaxation.